# how to trigger reactor stream

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

Here is my code, getShopDeliveryDate method will try to retrieve data from redis, if does not exist in redis, will invoke getFallbackValue method, getFallbackValue will call api to get data and then covert retrieved value to string, my question is:
if I invoke getDeliveryDate(id, info) in main method, it does not work, no data is inserted into redis and no data was printed on log.info("value***** {}", value)
what's wrong? client.getShopDeliveryDateInfo(id) is using webClient, will return Mono

`getDeliveryDate(id, info);`

```
public void getDeliveryDate(String id, Info info) {

        service.getDeliveryDate(id)
                      .doOnNext(value -> log.info("value***** {}", value))
                      .map(deliveryDateInfo -> info.deliveryDateInfo(deliveryDateInfo))
                      .switchIfEmpty(Mono.fromSupplier(() -> {
                          itemInfo.setErrorCode("error");
                          return info;
                      }))
    }
```

```
        public Mono<String> getDeliveryDate(String id) {
        final String key = id;
        return deliveryDateOperations.opsForValue()
                                              .get(key)
                                              .switchIfEmpty(getFallbackValue(id))
                                              .flatMap(value -> deliveryDateOperations.opsForValue()
                                                                                      .setIfAbsent(key, value, ttl)
                                                                                      .thenReturn(value));
       }
```

```
    Mono<String> getFallbackValue(String id) {
        return client.getDeliveryDateInfo(id)
                            .map(response -> convertDataToString(response));
    }
```

Comment: It's because you never actually request the data so it doesn't have a reason to execute anything (it's Reactive because it reacts to something). Guessing by the method name you need to return it (as `Mono<String>`, I guess) and use somewhere. Or at least call `.subscribe()` if you don't really need the result.

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to that flow because your main method is not executing that flow.

```
.subscribe()
```

Also if you wanna log something, I suggest you use

```
.doOnSuccess()
```